# É possível usar efeitos jQuery com tag <option> de um <select>?

Tags: php, html, jquery, css

Queria usar um efeito jQuery, por exemplo o `hide()`. É possível implementar este efeito ao clicar num `<option>`?

```
<div class="form-group" style="margin-left: 10px;margin-right:10px;width:50%;">
    <label>Selecione a categoria</label><br>
    <select class="form-control" name="categoria" id="cat" required>
        <option value="0" disabled selected hidden>Categoria</option>
        <option class="bt1">Impressão Digital (frente)</option>
        <option class="bt2" value="2">Impressão Digital (frente/verso)</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Neste caso, o meu objetivo era que ao clicar num destes `<option>` uma certa `<div>` se escondesse (usando `hide()`).

Já tentei usando este código jQuery e não funciona:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".bt1").click(function() {
            $(".div1").siblings().hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vc não consegue ligar o evento de **clique** diretamente ao `option`, mas, consegue pegar o option que foi selecionado com o método [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) e usando o seletor [:selected](https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) verificar se é o que deseja, se for é só dar um hide() na div:

```js
$(() => {
  $('#cat').on('click', function() {
    if($(this).find(":selected").hasClass('bt1')) $('.div1').toggle();
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group" style="margin-left: 10px;margin-right:10px;width:50%;">
  <label>Selecione a categoria</label><br>
  <select class="form-control" name="categoria" id="cat" required>
    <option value="0" disabled selected hidden>Categoria</option>
    <option class="bt1">Impressão Digital (frente)</option>
    <option class="bt2" value="2">Impressão Digital (frente/verso)</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="div1" style="margin-top: 30px; background: #ccc">teste</div>
```

Comment: Olá LeAndrade, usei a sua lógica. O único problema que encontrei é que após selecionar outros <option> e voltar a selecionar um previamente selecionado, ele escondia todos as divs (incluindo aquela que pretendo que mostre. Então decidi apenas acrescentar o método show() no código que apresentou e resolveu o meu problema. Obrigado pela ajuda :)

Comment: Legal que ajudou Luís, sucesso aí!

Answer (score 0):

Oi, é possível sim. Tente algo como:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".cat").change(function() {
            if($(this).val() == 0){
               $(".div").siblings().hide();
            }
            if($(this).val() == 1){
               $(".div1").siblings().hide();
            }
            
        });
    });
</script>
```

Basicamente você pega alteração do valor do input e baseado nele aplica a sua lógica

Comment: Olá Eduardo Worrel. Tentei resolver o meu problema usando o seu código mas não funcionou. Obrigado na mesma :)